# tslint method return type documentation

Tags: node.js, typescript, tslint

I have two nodejs projects with same package.json tsconfig.json and tslint.json files (just copies). When i'm calling tslint on both projects i have different results. In first project everything works fine, but in second i've got **Documentation must exist for properties** lint error.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "target": "ES6",        
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "noLib": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "scripthost"],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "./"
},
"include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "test.ts"
    // "test/**/*",
    // "bdd/**/*.ts"
]    
}
```

tslint.json:

```
{
"defaultSeverity": "error",
"extends": [
    "tslint:recommended"
],
"jsRules": {},
"rules": {
    "completed-docs": [
        true,
        {
            "properties": {
                "privacies": [
                    "public",
                    "protected"
                ]
            },
            "methods": {
                "privacies": [
                    "public",
                    "protected"
                ]
            },
            "classes": true,
            "functions": true,
            "interfaces": true,
            "namespaces": true,
            "types": true                
        }
    ],
    "max-line-length": false,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": false,
    "max-classes-per-file": false,
    "array-type": false,
    "file-header": true,
    "only-arrow-functions": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false
},
"rulesDirectory": []
}
```

package.json:

```
{


 "name": "testProj",
  "version": "18.9.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": {
    "name": "Me"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint test.ts --project ./tsconfig.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/request": "^2.47.0",
    "request": "^2.87.0",
    "request-debug": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.0.10",
    "@types/mocha": "^2.2.44",
    "asposestoragecloud": "^1.0.5",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "cucumber": "^3.0.0",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-cucumber": "0.0.23",
    "gulp-typescript": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "mocha": "^4.0.1",
    "mocha-cases": "^0.2.1",
    "mocha-jenkins-reporter": "^0.4.0",
    "mocha-sinon": "^2.0.0",
    "sinon": "^4.1.3",
    "ts-node": "^4.0.2",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

test.ts:

```
    /**
 * Some awesome class
 */
export class MyCheckClass {
    /**
     * Very usefull method
     * @param checkParameter Some unused parameter
     */
        public myCheckMethod(checkParameter: string): Promise<{ code: number, data: string }> {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                resolve({code : 200, data: "My Success Data"});
            });
        }
    }
```

Tried to add @ts-ignore - not helped, tried to add documentation for return type using @typedef - useless. 
What is the right way to make linter not to check documentation for such cases, or at least how to create proper documentation for return type?

PS. In first project, where such cases not causes linter to raise an error - everything the same. But what i found - if i'm using globally installed tslint (just uninstalled node_modules folder) - same errors appears, but after **npm install** - works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "documentation must exist" complaint you're seeing is from TSLint (not TypeScript). `// @ts-ignore` only applies to TypeScript complaints (not TSLint) so that won't help with it.

Instead, you have a couple options:

- Disable the [`completed-docs`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/completed-docs) rule in your `tslint.json` file with a `"completed-docs": false` inside the `"rules"` object ([docs](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/))
- Use `// tslint:disable-next-line:completed-docs` ([docs](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/))

For context, TSLint and TypeScript are two separate tools. TypeScript is the language that converts your `.ts`/`.tsx` files to `.js`; TSLint uses TypeScript to scan your code for issues.

As to why you're seeing different TSLint behavior across different projects, perhaps your versions are different? TSLint 5.13 changed how `completed-docs` runs compared to 5.12.

Comment: In both projects tslint versions are the same. Ok, thx, second way is working fine. But maybe there is some way to generate documentation for this case?

Comment: This looks like it might be a bug in completed-docs. It should be picking up on the fact that your `myCheckMethod` has documentation. Adding in a `@returns` comment shouldn't do anything.

Perhaps it's complaining about the `code` property? This is a known issue with the rule that should be fixed: https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4396